# Make college / university stay on it's own line in cv

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

For the jobs cv in the education section when you add / edit a section you can give the degree which has it's own text box.  Along with that you can enter the university / college that you obtained this degree.  It looks like this:

[image]

Looks great, however, when you save your changes the university is jumbled with the degree / specialty.  Can it have it's own line to keep it nice and consistent?  Here's what it ends up looking like right now:

[image]

To me the name of the university should stand directly under the specialty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report, JonH. This was fixed earlier tonight courtesy of [The Cottenmancer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3281191/courtny?tab=profile) (the experience section too).

Comment: It was an honor, a glaring design oversight corrected!

Comment: @Jason Punyon - you got to admit this fix was totally worth it, check anyone's cv now - it looks 100% better than before, very clean.  Thanks Cottenmancer whomever you are.

Answer (score 0):

The entire CV is due for a re-design so we're going to decline this for now.

Comment: Ok please fix the experience area as well same issue.